# add photo protototype method not defined js

Tags: javascript

hi everyone im new to oop in javascript and im trying to make an object model that allows me to store strings that represent a Photo. the  Album object should allow you to add a new photo, list all photos, and access a specific photo by the order it was added. but im getting an error that photos.addphoto is not defined. Can someone please

```
    function photo(location,filename){

this.location=location;
this.filename=filename;

}

function album(){

this.photos=[]
}



photo.prototype.addphoto=function(photo){

this.photos.push(photo)
}


photo.prototype.listphoto=function()
{

  return this.photos
}

photo.prototype.getphoto=function(){

  return this.photo[index-1]
}


var eurtope= new photo("new york","new york.jpg")
var russiae= new photo("england","england.jpg")
var photos=new album()



photos.addphoto(russiae)
photos.addphoto(eurtope)
photos.listphoto(album)

console.log(listphoto(

))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of issues, but the main one was that you were adding functions to the `photo.prototype` whereas you probably meant to add the functions to the `album.prototype`.

```js
function photo(location,filename){
    this.location=location;
    this.filename=filename;
}

function album(){
    this.photos=[];
}

album.prototype.addphoto=function(photo){
    this.photos.push(photo);
}

album.prototype.listphoto=function(){
    return this.photos;
}

album.prototype.getphoto=function(index){
    return this.photos[index];
}

var eurtope = new photo("new york","new york.jpg");
var russiae = new photo("england","england.jpg");
var photos = new album();

photos.addphoto(russiae);
photos.addphoto(eurtope);
photos.listphoto(album);

console.log(photos.listphoto());
console.log(photos.getphoto(0));
console.log(photos.getphoto(1));
```